# C-c C-o org-open-at-point follows òrg file links only with C-u prefix

Tags: org-mode, org-link

I store and insert links to .org files or headers with `C-c l`/`C-c C-l` (`file:XXX/XXX.org` or `file:XXX/XXX.org::*Header`) but when I try to follow them with `C-c C-o` it is not directly opened in Emacs but a window asking to choose an external software to open the file pops up.
If I then select Emacs as default software, a new instance is started to open the link.

On the contrary if I use `C-u C-c C-o` on the same links, this is opened in a different buffer within the same Emacs instance.

I can not figure out why `C-c C-o` does not open the link automatically in Emacs but, on the contrary, overriding the default application with `C-u` does.
In my init file no combination is set for `C-c C-o` so the default behavior should work.

I'm running Emacs 28.1 on Windows 11 Pro and Org 9.6.3 installed from gnu repo.

Current value of `org-file-apps` is:

```
Value
(("\\.docx\\'" . default)
 ("\\.xlsx\\'" . default))

Original Value
((auto-mode . emacs)
 (directory . emacs)
 ("\\.mm\\'" . default)
 ("\\.x?html?\\'" . default)
 ("\\.pdf\\'" . default))
```

Current value of `org-file-apps-windowsnt` is:

```
Value
((remote . emacs)
 (system .
     #[514 "\300\301\"\207"
           [w32-shell-execute "open"]
           5 "\n\n(fn FILE PATH)"])
 (t .
    #[514 "\300\301\"\207"
      [w32-shell-execute "open"]
      5 "\n\n(fn FILE PATH)"]))
```

Comment: What is the value of the variable `org-file-apps`? Also, please share what OS you are running on and the value of the corresponding system-specific variable (`org-file-apps-macos`, org-file-apps-windownt` or `org-file-apps-gnu`). Please edit the question and add the information to the question, not in a comment.

Comment: I included the variables outcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably customize `org-file-apps` and *add* the two entries for `docx` and `xlsx`, *instead* of replacing the original entries. At the end, your `org-file-apps` should look like this:

```el
((auto-mode . emacs)
 (directory . emacs)
 ("\\.mm\\'" . default)
 ("\\.x?html?\\'" . default)
 ("\\.pdf\\'" . default)
 ("\\.docx\\'" . default)
 ("\\.xlsx\\'" . default))
```

I hope that that will do what you want but I have not tested (other than that it seems to work for me in general, but I don't use Windows).

Comment: Thanks for the tip, it works! I did not expect that including new options not overlapping with default values would still erase the other settings

Comment: The thing is that these were the old (default) options that make everything work, so you need to keep them around: you can *add* new options but you should not *remove* the old ones.